# Reading all contact data

Tags: android, contacts, contactscontract

I am on Android 2.3.3, API Level 10. I want to read all contacts and data associated to them, therefore e.g. all email addresses, phone numbers, custom fields...
I tried it like this:

```
Uri contactUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
Cursor contacts = managedQuery(contactUri, null, null, null, null );

contacts.moveToFirst();

do {
    for(int i=0;i<contacts.getColumnCount();i++)
    {
         System.out.println(contacts.getColumnName(i) + ": " + contacts.getString(i));
    }

    System.out.println("============\n\n");

} while (contacts.moveToNext());

contacts.close();
```

However this gives me only the following fields:

```
times_contacted: 0
contact_status: null
custom_ringtone: null
has_phone_number: 1
phonetic_name: null
phonetic_name_style: 0
contact_status_label: null
lookup: [removed]
contact_status_icon: null
last_time_contacted: 0
display_name: [removed]
sort_key_alt: [removed]
in_visible_group: 1
_id: 101
starred: 0
sort_key: [removed]
display_name_alt: [removed]
contact_presence: null
display_name_source: 40
contact_status_res_package: null
contact_chat_capability: null
contact_status_ts: null
photo_id: null
send_to_voicemail: 0
```

Where are the phone numbers, email addresses...? Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See Contact Contract API examples

http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Android-Contacts/

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, null);
    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        String id = cur.getString(
                    cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
    String name = cur.getString(
                    cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
    if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
        //Query phone here.  Covered next
        }
        }
}
}
```

Take a look at this example

http://code.google.com/p/android-contacts-contract-example/

Comment: Thank you, the link to the google code example and the tutorial linked from there (http://app-solut.com/blog/2011/03/working-with-the-contactscontract-to-query-contacts-in-android/) was really useful :-)